# XorShift number generation

Tags: python, c++, c, xor, shift

The same XorShift functions written in C and Python give different results. Can you explain it?

The XorShift function generates numbers in the following way:

```
x(0) = 123456789
y(0) = 362436069
z(0) = 521288629
w(0) = 88675123 

x(n+1) = y(n)
y(n+1) = z(n)
z(n+1) = w(n)
w(n+1) = w(n) ^ (w(n)>>19) ^ (x(n)^(x(n)<<11)) ^ ((x(n)^(x(n)<<11)) >> 8)
```

I wrote this function in Python to generate subsequent values of w:

```
X = 123456789
Y = 362436069
Z = 521288629
W = 88675123

def xor_shift():
    global X, Y, Z, W
    t = X ^ (X << 11)
    X = Y
    Y = Z
    Z = W
    W = W ^ (W >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8)
    return W

W1 = xor_shift() # 252977563114
W2 = xor_shift() # 646616338854
W3 = xor_shift() # 476657867818
```

The same code written in C (it can be found on Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift) gives different results:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t xor128(void) {
    static uint32_t x = 123456789;
    static uint32_t y = 362436069;
    static uint32_t z = 521288629;
    static uint32_t w = 88675123;
    uint32_t t;

    t = x ^ (x << 11);
    x = y; y = z; z = w;
    return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8);
}

cout << xor128() <<'\n'; // result W1 = 3701687786
cout << xor128() <<'\n'; // result W2 = 458299110
cout << xor128() <<'\n'; // result W3 = 2500872618
```

I suppose that there is a problem with my Python code or my use of cout (I am not very good at C++).

### **EDIT: Working solution:**

need to change the return value from `uint32_t` to `uint64_t`:

```
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t xor128(void) {
    static uint64_t x = 123456789;
    static uint64_t y = 362436069;
    static uint64_t z = 521288629;
    static uint64_t w = 88675123;
    uint64_t t;

    t = x ^ (x << 11);
    x = y; y = z; z = w;
    return w = w ^ (w >> 19) ^ t ^ (t >> 8);
}
```

Comment: How big is the maximum value of a `uint32_t`? There you go.

Comment: I would really appreciate if you could help me to write CORRECT xor_shift function in Python, because my clearly does not work :(

Comment: The maximum value of an unsigned 32-bit integer in decimal: **4294967295** (UINT32_MAX), which is less than the results in Python, which automatically promotes integer types on demand.

Comment: Okay but after changing it to uint64_t my result is still different from result in Python.  W1=3869459946 W2=2371244454 W3=4211465258

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change all your `uint32_t` types to `uin64_t` and you'll get the same result. The difference is the precision between `uint32_t` and the unlimited precision of python integer types.

Comment: After changing uint32_t to uint64_t I get: W1=3869459946
W2=2371244454
W3=4211465258

What is still different from Python values...

Comment: @PiterD Did you also change the return value type and the type of `t`? On my system with these changes I get the exact same values as the python program.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right I did not change the return value. Now the results are same :) Thank you!